# SMS formatting looks bad

Tags: twilio, zapier

I have been trying to get a well formatted text from zapier to send through twilio, the message should be send like this:

```
New patient!

Name
Phone Number
email@email.com

Contacting him ASAP!
```

Instead I'm receiving

```
New patient!NamePhone Numberemail!email.comContacting him ASAP!
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Could you try adding HTML tags? Perhaps the Twilio service renders low level HTML before sending. Try inserting <br> tags where you want new lines. Not sure it will work, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I got curious and tested it out. Wasn't able to reproduce your issue:

[image]

[image]

I just typed a regular "enter" for the newlines and also tried with your copied text. If it's still not working, can you update your question with screenshots of the zap input?

Comment: Hi Xavdid, I have been sending through twilio, and with some support from them I now know that is something about the unicode, or that says the carrier that is sending to Argentina. I'm not sure what would be the zap input, here is what I think it is: http://prntscr.com/mxk1vn
and
http://prntscr.com/mxk1pl

Comment: interesting! yeah, then it might be something Argentina-carrier specific. I'm in the US. I'd work with twilio to resolve, but unfortunately i'm not sure there's much zapier can do to help here. Sorry about that!